# How long does the cream in a freshly baked chicken pie last for?

Tags: storage-method, chicken, pie, cream

I am planning on baking a chicken pie that contains double cream tonight and serving it two days later.

How long does the cream in the freshly baked pie last for? Do you think it will be still okay after two days?

Comment: You mean that you will make the cream tonight, but put it in the pie itself on Sunday and serve? What cream is it exactly? And are you planning on storing the cream in the fridge?

Comment: i am putting double cream in a chicken pie that i am making

Answer (score 1):

(I am assuming the pie essentially contains chicken broth, either as an ingredient, or from cooking the chicken in the filling, and basing the hold time on that as the likely most perishable ingredient in the pie...)

Such a pie will be safe for two to three days (possibly more, but I like to treat safety conservatively....)

However, if you have a bottom crust, it will likely get quite soggy over that period of time.

If you need to prepare your pie ahead, it might be better from a quality perspective to prepare the filling stove top separately from the crust, and blind bake the crust.  Then on the night of service, you can combine the two and bake to heat through and crisp up the crust.  This will almost certainly give you a better product than making the pie fully in advance.

Comment: You might want to edit or delete your answer based on the additional information the OP added in the comment.

Comment: Safe in the fridge or on the counter?